# AWS Polly reads word 'proj' as 'project'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I have file names and Polly reads it in certain cases.
I have a file with name 'proj' but Polly reads it as 'project'. Why is it happening? Where to set up this kind of settings?

PS. I want Polly to read as is because it could be that someone used a shorthand 'proj' for words like 'projectile', 'projector' etc.

[image]

Here is SSML tab (@Nathan)

[image]

Comment: Can you share what the SSML looks like?

Comment: @Nathan, it is empty